# Fetch data hacia archivo php retorna null

Tags: php, fetch

Estoy intentando realizar una prueba de uso del fetch para enviar datos desde javascript hacia un front en php, sin embargo no logro tomar los datos y solo consigo un resultado NULL.

Lo estoy enviando mediante POST aunque probe mediante un GET y pasa lo mismo

Como nota, en la consola solo aparece la conexion en network luego de apretar F5, entiendo que para que funcione, ya deberia existir cuando ingreso a Test.php

**datosJS.js**

```
const profile= { 
    username: "Jonathan",
    email: "jonathan@gmail.com",
    password: "123456"
}
fetch('Test.php', {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-type" : "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(profile)
    }).then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
    });
```

**Test.php**

```
<script src="datosJS.js" type="text/javascript"></script> //lo uso para llamar a datosJS.js al ingresar a Test.php

<?php

 $body = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
    var_dump($body);
    
?>
```

Se que PHP funciona del lado del servidor y js del cliente, sin embargo me esta costando ver donde esta mi error.

Agradezco su ayuda !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno finalmente logre encontrar la solucion, debajo paso a detallarla:

**datosJS.js**

```
window.onload = function() {

let datos = {
   method: "POST",
   headers: {
            "Content-type" : "application/json"
   },
   body: JSON.stringify({ 
      username:"Jonathan",
      email:"jonathan@gmail.com",
      password:"123456"
  })
}

fetch('Test.php',datos)
.then(resp => resp.text())
.then(resp =>{
console.log(resp);
        document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = resp; 

    //document.querySelector('#results').innerHTML = resp; //funciona al igual que getElementById
    
})
}
```

**Test.php**

```
<script src="datosJS.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<section class="Section" id="results" name="results">

            <?php

            $body = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
            $nombre = $body['username'];

            echo  $nombre;
            echo  '</br>';
            print_r($body);
  
            ?>
```

Gracias al aporte de @Wilfredo en la respuesta de arriba que me ayudó a ver los datos en consola, debajo detallo las partes de codigo que faltaron para poder ver los datos en pagina y resolver el problema original:

- En datosJS.js agregar **document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = resp;** para setear el valor al item 'results' y envolver todo en **window.onload = function() {}** para que corra cuando este listo
- en Test.php indicarle a un "Div" o "Section" o lo que sea, **id="results" name="results"** donde se asignaran los datos y con un echo podra verse en pantalla.

Espero que a alguien le sirva en el futuro.
Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Te hace falta un `.then` y lo que devuelves desde el `php` no es un `json`  es un `text`

```
let datos = {
   method: "POST",
   headers: {
            "Content-type" : "application/json"
   },
   body: JSON.stringify({ 
      username:"Jonathan",
      email:"jonathan@gmail.com",
      password:"123456"
  })
}



fetch('Test.php',datos)
.then(resp => resp.text())
.then(resp =>{
    console.log(resp)
})
```

Puedes ver la respuesta en la consola del navegador.  con la tecla `F12` para `chrome`

**Notas**

- El documento `Test.php` debe estar en la misma carpeta que el
  documento donde estas ejecutando el `fetch`.
- El documento `Test.php` debe llamarse así `Test.php` "mayúsculas incluidas"

Comment: Excelente, si bien ahora logro ver el arreglo completo en consola, mediante var_dump la salida en la pagina sigue siendo 'NULL' aunque no logro descifrar el porque =/ –